# Unable to push an image to GCP container registry

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, containers, registry, push

Error Message:
unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

Steps I've tried:

- gcloud auth login
- gcloud auth configure-docker

I'm on a Mac (11.5.2)

And I have the necessary GCP permissions to push to the container registry.

Any other suggestions please?

Comment: did you try a gcloud auth application-default login also?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but still the same result

Comment: Which command do you use? docker push? What are your roles on the project?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere 
docker build -t <image name>:latest .

docker push <image name>:latest

Storage Admin Role

Comment: Does your image name start with *.gcr.io?